# How to disable auto append .js extension when babel a non-extension file

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

In express.js, the bin/www file has no extension.

I did try below command,

```
$ babel -d build src/bin/www
```

And result was...

```
src/bin/www -> build/src/bin/www.js
```

It seems like the babel appended a .js extension for non-extension file automatically.

Can I disable this?

---

Added additional information.

I figured out that

```
$ babel -d build src/bin/www.es6 

src/bin/www.es6 -> build/src/bin/www.js
```

It seems like the babel change all non-js-extension files to `.js`

Can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to disable this behavior.

Since your workflow is reasonably customized, the best option for you would probably be a custom script either implemented yourself or via `gulp`. Babel's CLI is very basic and really only indented for simple usecases. If you need something more, putting it together yourself is your best bet.

An alternative would be to have the `bin` folder not be transpiled at all, and have `bin/www` simply do `require('../build/bin/www.js')` so the extension does not matter.

Comment: I down-voted this answer, because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AlexandruNedelcu Okay, added a line saying specifically that it isn't supported.